# received status code 400 invalid value 'ipaddress' for no_key

Tags: node.js, express, chef-infra

i use [chef-api](https://github.com/normanjoyner/chef-api) for express js  and i wanna get only the ip address of node " server 1 " from a chef-server

im sending a request like this

Code  :

```
chef.partialSearch("node", "name:server1",{"ip":"ipaddress"} ,function(err, res){

  if (err){console.log(error);}

  else{console.log(res);}

});
```

Or

```
chef.partialSearch("node", { q: "name:server1"} ,{"ip":"ipaddress"} ,function(err, res){
....
});
```

=>  Response :

```
received status code 400 invalid  value 'ipaddress' for no_key
```

function in code source :

```
partialSearch: function(index, qs, data, fn){
            http_methods.post([config.host_url, "search", index].join("/"), qs, data, function(err, response){
                return fn(err, response);
            });
        }
```

and i cant understand the correct syntax for the request (http) from the official website doc [api_chef_server](https://docs.chef.io/api_chef_server.html#id76)
Can you please give a valid syntax with example .
Thanks

Comment: Are you always planning to access a single node at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly i found the correct syntax for both request

**Simple Search :**

```
    chef.search("node", {q: "name:server1" }, function(err, res){

       if (err){console.log(error);}

       else{console.log(res);}

     });
```

**Partial Search :**

```
chef.partialSearch("node", "chef_environment:prod", { name: ['name'] , 'ipaddress': ['ipaddress'] }, function(err, res){

        if (err){console.log(error);}

        else{console.log(res);}


    });
```

**Hope this can help someone else who is still looking .**

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is something like this:

```
chef.getNode('server1', function(err, node) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(node.automatic.ipaddress);
});
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply , and yes its a solution if you wanna request for only one server but if you wanna get all " ipaddress " for all servers belongs to a " role " isnt a good pratice for the performance of your chef-server and even the time reply of the application
take a look 
http://dougireton.com/blog/2013/01/19/get-chef-clients-by-version/
and
http://engineering.voxer.com/2013/03/22/chef-part-2-performance/
and i found the correct syntax , Thanks again for your reply :D

Comment: That is correct, which is why I asked if you understated your use case :)